# Calculating the price with radio value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

Apparently this should be doing but doesn't work :

http://jsfiddle.net/9baeJ/

HTML :

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label>
        20
        <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb1" value="20" />
    </label>

    <label>
        35
        <input id="fb4" type="radio" name="fb1" value="35" />
    </label>

    <label>
         10
         <input id="fb1" type="radio" name="fb" value="10" />
     </label>

    <label>
        15
        <input id="fb2" type="radio" name="fb" value="15" />
    </label>
    <br/>
    Total: <span id="totalScore">0</span>€
</form>
```

And the js :

```
var sum = 0;
$("#myForm").find("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function (i, e){sum+=$(e).val();});
$("#totalScore").val(sum);
```

I tried everything I saw here in stackoverflow but I don't get what's wrong with the code. Actually this solution is one of the examples that somebody already posted.

Comment: what are you trying to do??

Comment: What the title says, calculate the total with the radio values

Comment: It is working correctly then. checked in chrome.

Comment: It isn't in Mozilla EDIT: Ok the link bugged and didn't save the changes, I'm changing the link at the question

Comment: @user3506043:works correctly in mozilla too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trythis

```
function calcscore(){
    var score = 0;
    $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){
        score+=parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#totalScore").text(score)
}
$().ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        calcscore()
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AMLHq/407/)

Answer (score 0):

Span does not have value, you must use .text() or .html(). You also need to wrap the code with DOM ready handler.

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $("#myForm").find("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function () {
            sum += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#totalScore").text(sum);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/AMLHq/408/)

Comment: Okay looks like this isn't working and I still don't know why, but I get the point you are talking about.

Comment: this is working at the fiddle but that's just a part of the html and I don't know why it doesn't work when I implement it. So anyway, I got the point you were talking about and will think about it the next time I face a span problem.

Comment: @user3506043 Well the problem is most likley that you are missing a DOM ready handler like this `$(function(){});` i'll update the answer

Comment: Yes I am dumb, I was just testing everything (not only code from here)doing ctrl+c ctrl+v, sorry mate.